# fail to satisfy = frustrate?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Is it correct to say that if a person fails to ***satisfy*** one of his or her needs then that person ***frustrates*** that need?

As I am not a native English speaker, I need to apologize for being unclear. I am going to rephrase it as follows.
If I manage to satisfy a certain need then, unless I am wrong, we can say that I have satisfied my need (for example I can satisfy my psychological need to belong by being accepted in a peer group). If I ***fail to satisfy*** this need (for example because I have been rejected by other peer group members), what is it more appropriate to say? That I have got my need ***frustrated***, ***dissatisfied***, or what?

Comment: A person who's need is not satisfied may be frustrated but the need is not frustrated.

Comment: @thanmour Do you mean frustrate in the sense of activley thwarting someone's need deliberately, or of inadvertently falling short of the mark?

Comment: @Kristina Lopez - you mean "whose need", I think.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHarvey.  You'd think a native speaker would know that but I have a mental block against "whose".  To me, it should be possessive! :-D

Comment: Are you looking for an adjective or a verb? Can you give a stand alone sentence where you want to put this word or phrase you seek?

Comment: Both "satisfy" and "frustrate" have diverse meanings, so it's impossible to say that one can substitute for the other in most uses.

Comment: I thank you all for  your contribution and your follow-up questions. 
So, my question was (or supposed to be) whether we can conceive the noun "frustration" as opposite of "frustration".

Answer (score 1):

Among the definitions of *to frustrate* that appear in the O.E.D., the one that seems to be the most relevant here is ‘to balk, disappoint (a hope, expectation, etc.)’. The ‘etc.’ in the definition may be taken to cover needs, so it does not seem unreasonable to speak of one’s needs being frustrated, and indeed a casual search will readily reveal examples of such constructions. One **could** use *to frustrate a need* as the opposite of *to satisfy a need*, but only in certain contexts. The phrase *to frustrate a need* is not always  interchangeable with *to not satisfy a need*, for the following reasons.

**(1)** The word *to frustrate* would typically be understood to imply that some active effort is involved, that we are not dealing with a mere failure to act. If pure laziness results in some need not being satisfied, that would not normally be described as frustrating the need.

**(2)** One can speak of satisfying one’s own needs and of satisfying the needs of others. On the other hand, while one can frustrate the needs of others, it would be very odd to speak of frustrating one’s own needs. That is probably a consequence of (1): absent some highly unusual circumstances, people don’t actively work on preventing the satisfaction of their own needs.

**(3)** To speak of somebody frustrating somebody’s need is apt only if there is some reasonable expectation that one would satisfy it.

**(4)** While the verb *to frustrate* can take *need* (as well as *hope, expectation, desire, want,* etc.) as its object, it nowadays much more often takes some noun standing for a person as its object.

Answer (score -2):

I would go with 'Dissatisfy'. Sounds way more appropriate than frustrate to me

Comment: This feels wrong to me.  While you can satisfy a person or satisfy a need / requirement, I believe that "dissatisfy" can apply only to people (e.g., "Windows 8 dissatisfied many users").

Answer (score -2):

For **failed to satisfy** I would say the need is **unsatisfied** or **unfulfilled**.

Frustrate (in my opinion) has more of an emotional and active meaning. My need could be for water.  If I don't get water my reaction may be one of frustration (emotional reaction), but it may be that I just get more thirsty.

Dissatisfy would fit if someone offered me something else which was not satisfactory.  I needed water, they gave me vinegar or something else which didn't meet my expectations.